# how to multiply value selected from a spinner to a textview to display result in another text view

Tags: android, android-spinner

i want to multiply the credits by the gradePoints to return the gradevalue in textview2. how do i do that? the credits is the second spinner.                                                `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

```
String[] grades ={"A","B+","B","C+","C", "D+", "D", "E"};

String[] credits ={"1","2","3","4"};
double [] points1 = {4.0, 3.5, 3.0, 2.5, 2.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0 };


Spinner spinner;
TextView TextView1;
TextView TextView2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gradePoints);
    TextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gradeValue);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, grades);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener1);

    Spinner spin2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, credits);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener1 = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String s1 = String.valueOf(points1[position]);
        TextView1.setText(s1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
};


public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id ){
    Spinner spin = (Spinner)parent;
    Spinner spin2 = (Spinner)parent;

    if(spin.getId() == R.id.spinner)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your choice :" + grades[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if(spin2.getId() == R.id.spinner2)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your choice :" + credits[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Choose grades :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    String[] grades ={"A","B+","B","C+","C", "D+", "D", "E"};

    String[] credits ={"1","2","3","4"};
    double [] points1 = {4.0, 3.5, 3.0, 2.5, 2.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0 };


    Spinner spinner, spin2;
    TextView TextView1;
    TextView TextView2;
    Double point = -1.0;
    Double value = -1.0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gradePoints);
        TextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gradeValue);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, grades);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener1);

        spin2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, credits);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener1 = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            point = points1[position];
            TextView1.setText(String.valueOf(point));

            if ( value != -1.0 ) {
                double res = (double) point * value;
                TextView2.setText(String.valueOf(res));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    };


    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id ){

        Toast.makeText(this, "Your choice :" + credits[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String valueStr = credits[position];
        value = Double.parseDouble(valueStr);

        if ( point != -1.0 ) {
            double res = (double) point * value;
            TextView2.setText(String.valueOf(res));
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Choose grades :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Hope this will work!

Comment: Thanks, I'm happy that it helped!

Comment: is there a way to increase the number of rows for this activity using the code you supplied?

Comment: I don't understand..can you explain in more detail?

Comment: the code I asked for help with was for a single row, now I want to increase the number of rows to perform the same function like the single row. so how do inflate the rows to 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making your selected values member variables then changing the value of the textview each time it's selected:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    int selectedCredit = 0;
    double selectedPoints = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        int[] credits ={1,2,3,4}; 
        double[] points = {4.0, 3.5, 3.0, 2.5, 2.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0 };

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                selectedCredit = credits[position];
                double value = selectedCredit * selectedPoints;
                textView.setText("The calculated value is " + value);
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){}
        });

        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                selectedPoints = points[position];
                double value = selectedCredit * selectedPoints;
                textView.setText("The calculated value is " + value);
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){}
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: after using the code you gave it showed that some of the variables were not initialised. thank you for your help. i have the desired result now.

Answer (score 0):

I have given a solution according to what I understood from your question. Hope this helps. :)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

String[] grades ={"A","B+","B","C+","C", "D+", "D", "E"};

String[] credits ={"1","2","3","4"};
double [] points1 = {4.0, 3.5, 3.0, 2.5, 2.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0 };


Spinner spinner;
TextView TextView1;
TextView TextView2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gradePoints);
    TextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gradeValue);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, grades);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener1);

    Spinner spin2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, credits);
    spin2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

    spinner.OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener1 = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String s1 = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        TextView1.setText(s1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
};

    spin2.OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener1 = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String s1 = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Double gradePoint = 0.0;
        if(s1.equals("A")){
           gradePoint = 4.0;
        }
         else if(s1.equals("B+")){
           gradePoint = 3.5;
        }
         else if(s1.equals("B")){
           gradePoint = 3.0;
        }
         else if(s1.equals("C+")){
           gradePoint = 2.5;
        }
         else if(s1.equals("c")){
           gradePoint = 2.0;
        }
         else if(s1.equals("D+")){
           gradePoint = 1.5;
        }
         else if(s1.equals("D")){
           gradePoint = 1.0;
        }
         else if(s1.equals("E")){
           gradePoint = 0;
        }
        int courseCredit = Integer.parseInt(spin2.getSelectedItem().toString());
         double result = gradePoint*courseCredit;
         TextView2.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
};


public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id ){
    Spinner spin = (Spinner)parent;
    Spinner spin2 = (Spinner)parent;

    if(spin.getId() == R.id.spinner)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your choice :" + grades[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if(spin2.getId() == R.id.spinner2)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your choice :" + credits[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Choose grades :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but a few errors showed because some of them were not initialised. thank you for your help.

Comment: OK, i must have made some mistakes. Do you have your desired result?